# How to apply border to a box() in R shiny?

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to assign **border** to a box() in shinyApp. I have two boxes in shinyApp.
I want to assign border to *1st box()* only. How to do it?
Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$style(HTML( ".box {border: 5px solid #3DA0D1;}")),
  box("border", 123,background = 'navy'),
  box("line", 123,background = 'navy'))))
server <- function(input,output){

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any help, would be appreciable.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box("border", 123, background = 'navy'),
    box("line", 123, background = 'navy'),
    tags$script(HTML("$('.box').eq(0).css('border', '5px solid #3DA0D1');"))
  )
))
server <- function(input,output){}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: But here is a problem, 'border' in 1st box is not text, it is a variable having some value. Then the border is not working for 'border' variable.